# configure Magento 2.3 with Will-Call only shipping method

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.3

I have put together a store for my Rose Club's annual fund-raiser.  Unlike most of you customers, we do not do any shipping or deliver, but rather have two weekends where the livestock (roses and other perishable plant material) can be picket up.

How do I configure magento 2.3 to skip the shipping step, or configure a "Will-Call" shipping method as the only option?